# How to catch event from the wheel button on Android HeadUnit

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

[image]

I have a case that need to handle the event of wheel button (on the left side of screen). But i am not sure which truly events i can get from where and how to handle because i test some apps, when i try to wheel the button, the view turns to selected state like we handle focus in Android TV.
I have researched there are 2 callbacks which may help to resolve this usecase: `onDispatchKey` and `onGenericMotionEvent`. But i don't know how about of reality.